# Gitlab ci automatically trigger another pipeline in another project

Tags: gitlab-ci

Let's assume that i have a project (`firstProject`) with it's pipeline (which is a test pipeline)

And another project (`secondProject`) with it's pipeline (build, test, build publish ...)

What i want to do :

After the `secondProject` pipeline finishes, automatically trigger the `firstProject` pipeline

I did that and it's working fine with :

```
Android:
  stage : Trigger-cross-projects
  trigger: repo/project
```

But the `secondProject` doesn't wait for the result of the `firstProject` pipeline, and that's what I want to do, do you have any idea how to make the `secondProject` wait for the result of the `firstProject` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use

```
      strategy: depend
```

For more information: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html